# Cannot load to Resource in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My site is: blog.moranow.com, I has error cannot load to resource js and css file. this code below in functions.php in my theme.

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mora-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mora-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js',
            array( 'jquery' ),
            null,
            true );
}
```

[error](https://zeno-front-moranow.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/avatars/Screenshot+from+2019-07-05+13-07-27.png)

Comment: AccessDeniedRequest has expired3002019-07-05T10:41:28Z2019-07-05T10:43:44Z1D66CD26445406BBGRzC2tdp6bTMQR6BgP8eZ+ZCc7IqLd9H+dNGbisbI9VIEiy43n7KeRygU2I+cwRkM7ZVUxQptfs= --- Is this your error? please check link.

Comment: sorry, my fault, I've edited my link